# Tesseract OCR read text from photo

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I have more than 5000 of images like below. Text in the images have 10 variants like `T122 R-2` `T123 R-12` `T45 R-1` etc.

[image]

I want to read text in the image but result is like below.

```
, | 5 ğ ve . > | >
İmes <ğ
de 3
U | | i
( ' g
i : .
İM ; »
| ? > e
* >
| NN | va
, İ
( di
(Ny ,
i
>
i |
, > N i | Ni
```

How can I improve OCR accuracy ?

I have tried various of filters but result is almost same.

I am familiar with tesseract so it's better for me to use it but If there is better OCR I can try it as well.

P.S. I know Google Vision has better results but I couldn't find a way to automate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any OCR should be able to handle that image without a problem if you roughly deskew first

[image]

so using CLI deskew https://github.com/galfar/deskew

read the options so in this case needed to change with -a 89

```
deskew -a angle:  Maximal expected skew angle (both directions) in degrees (default: 10)
```

***also worth adding -b 000000 to black fill background and set output to .pgm***

```
Deskew 1.30 (2019-06-07) x64 by Marek Mauder
http://galfar.vevb.net/deskew/

Preparing input image (yRXJb.jpg [2000x1500/R8G8B8]) ...
Calculating skew angle...

Skew angle found [deg]: -75.025
Rotating image...

Saving output (\deskewed-yRXJb.pgm [1966x2320/Gray8]) ...

Done!
```

For Tesseract there may be better adjustments in some cases such as threshold but I left at default for the one test case and tesseract needs either `--psm 11` or --psm 12 to see the text in this busy image.

***I would have hoped for `T122 -R-2` but got `T122 R-2` and can't seem to better that without considering training.***

[image]

Comment: When I deskew same image `yRXJb.jpg`, result is `Skew angle found [deg]: 8.430`. This makes image text direction towards up. However, Tesseract still can't find anything on this image. I've looked at Kadmos and it looks a commercial app.

Comment: I have just tried `-a 90` and got same angle result with you but tesseract returns empty file.

Comment: I've tried with Irfanview and got same result with you but it requires mouse selection. I tried `out.tif` and `out.ppm` with tesseract but still no recognition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245867/discussion-between-x999-and-k-j).

Answer (score 1):

OCR-Tesseract have many corner points which gives inappropriate results. One of these is rotation. Documentation says:

> The quality of Tesseract’s line segmentation reduces significantly if
> a page is too skewed, which severely impacts the quality of the OCR.

Before come to the others, the biggest problem is rotation in your case. So you should figure it out firstly.

Second is noise which gives different kind of letters as result. To improve it you can check the [tesseract documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)(**Improving the quality of the output**
) which is very clear.

Also I can suggest you to use the method which I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70020684/11048887) before. First detect the text then recognize the letters inside. This will help you not to recognize unexpected letters.