# How to prevent tesseract from detecting in certain angles?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I have an image which contains text in 2 different orientations:

[image: image which contains text in 2 different orientations]

I just want to detect the text which is *vertically* aligned.
Even though I rotated the image, tesseract seems to be detecting the orientation with the best output possible.

How can I **prevent** tesserect from choosing the *more promising orientation*?

```
img = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I updated the post with some code, I think it doesn't really explain anything important though...

Comment: you may chech [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72655327/11048887)

Comment: To clarify: 

I have this image with text in two different alignments (horizontal, vertical).
I am only interested in the **vertical** aligned text. 
But Tesseract detects all the text contained in the image and since the majority of text in this image is horizontally aligned, it (understandably) sets the focus of detection on horizontally aligned texts.

Can I tell tesseract the angle of detection I am interested in? 
It doesn't even need to be an automated process.

Answer (score 1):

you can just reduce the brightness of the image while preprocessing. I had tried the same thing with **easyocr**

```
import easyocr
import cv2
import numpy as np

# reduce brightness of image
def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):
   invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
   table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
      for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")
   return cv2.LUT(image, table)


gamma = 0.29
img = cv2.imread('4fLki.png')
img = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
adjusted = adjust_gamma(img, gamma=gamma)
cv2.imwrite('resize.png',adjusted)
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'],gpu=False)
result = reader.readtext('resize.png')
for detection in result:
        print(detection)
```

The ouput is

```
([[174, 20], [328, 20], [328, 44], [174, 44]], 'N" 138 Abril 2022', 0.6718160011919738)
```