# Use Tesseract in R to detect black writing on white label from photo with multicolored background

Tags: r, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to auto detect a number from a black on white label within a photograph, and rename the image with that number.
I'm struggling to optimize the image for OCR recognition, isolate the 5 digit number that I want from the rest of the text that's also on the label (there is only 1x large text 5 digit number, but it may be repeated multiple times and there are other numbers on the label) & autodetect the orientation of the image- I plan on running a for loop to detect the label from all images within a folder, and they are not all oriented in the same way.
The colors in the background will vary from the example provided, but never be black on white. The label is not always in the same place. I haven't gotten to the code for renaming the file yet- bonus points if you do.

```
`
library(tesseract)
library(magick)
library(stringr)

white<-tesseract(options=list(editor_image_word_bb_color='white',stopper_smallword_size=5,tessedit_char_whitelist = "0123456789abcde"))

label<-  magick::image_read("file.jpg")%>%
    magick::image_convert('tiff')%>%
      magick::image_resize("2000x") %>%
  magick::image_rotate(180) %>%
  magick::image_convert(type = 'Grayscale')%>%
  magick::image_level(black_point=80,
                      white_point=81)  %>%
  magick::image_reducenoise()%>%
  magick::image_trim(fuzz = 65)%>%
  tesseract::ocr(engine=white)

label`
```

The above code doesn't reliably detect the 5-digit number & I have to manually change the image_rotate value to find the correct orientation for a hopeful output (hopeful being that I can see the 5 digits in the correct order, not that it's perfect). The label is not always in the same place, so it doesn't help to autocrop the image to remove noise. I would then pipeline into a string recognition, similar to below, but that needs work depending on the output of the above.

'  str_extract("\b\d{5}\b")'

[image: photo of biological panel with label in photo][image: alternative photo]

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to extract the numbers with the following code which is not using Tessseract but is using the OCR of the Word software :

```
library(pdftools)
library(RDCOMClient)
library(magick)

################################################
#### Step 1 : We convert the image to a PDF ####
################################################

path_PDF <- "D:\\im.pdf"
path_JPG <- "D:\\im.jpg"
path_Word <- "D:\\im.docx"

pdf(path_PDF, height = 12, width = 8)

im <- image_read(path_JPG)
plot(im)
dev.off()

####################################################################
#### Step 2 : We use the OCR of Word to convert the PDF to word ####
####################################################################
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_PDF),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc$SaveAs2(path_Word)

###############################################
#### Step 3 : Convert word document to pdf ####
###############################################
wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]$SaveAs(path_PDF, FileFormat = 17) # FileFormat = 17 saves as .PDF
doc$Close()
wordApp$Quit() # quit wordApp

########################################
#### Step 4 : Extract text from PDF ####
########################################
strsplit(pdf_text(path_PDF), "\n")
[[1]]
 [1] "7/434?."                                                                                 
 [2] ""                                                                                        
 [3] ""                                                                                        
 [4] ""                                                                                        
 [5] ""                                                                                        
 [6] "                 Bay CI                        Block 2752 Rank              2752      21"
 [7] "                           Block Middle Dock                     RETRIEVE"               
 [8] "                                                                 DATE"                   
 [9] "                Deployed        6/21/2022"                                               
[10] ""                                                                                        
[11] ""                                                                                        
[12] ""                                                                                        
[13] ""                                                                                        
[14] "                                                        21996"                           
[15] "                etrieved"                                                                
[16] ""                                                                                        
[17] ""                                                                                        
[18] ""                                                                                        
[19] "                PVC                                                                2199t"
```

Comment: Your results look fantastic! unfortunately I get the following error code when I try to open the path_PDF. Any thoughts?
<Error: Exception occurred.
checkErrorInfo> -2147352567 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567

Comment: I think it's the plot(im) that isn't working- when I try to open the pdf, I get a file corrupt error. I'll try to trouble shoot before proceeding.

Comment: Which version or R are you using?

Comment: The idea is to transform the JGP image into a PDF document. Once you have done this, you can use the OCR of the Word document to transform the PDF document into a Word document. Afterwards, you can transform the Word document to a searchable PDF and extract the text from the searchable PDF.

Comment: Version 4.2.2 'pdf(path_PDF, height=24, width=12)' Creates a pdf that I'm unable to open (Not a PDF/corrupted- has 0 pages). im<-image_read(path_JPG), plot(im) plots the image. Am I missing the line that 'writes' the JPG to PDF?

Comment: The code that is taking the JPG and transforms it into a PDF file is :         
pdf(path_PDF, height = 12, width = 8)
im <- image_read(path_JPG)
plot(im)
dev.off()

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help & would give you a thumbs up if I had that power. My error- I was running it line by line within Rmd without 'running' it.  But now I get the same error as above when I hit Step 3 wordApp...SaveAs
```<checkErrorInfo> -2147352567 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
Error: Exception occurred.``` Anecdotally, I also only see the image in the word.doc that remains open on screen, I'm not seeing anything OCRed.

Comment: Hi, did you try running this code outside of the RMD to see if it works? On my end, I executed the code in RStudio on Windows and not in a RMD.

Comment: I did, no joy. Still get the error. I think it's because of the doc$SaveAs2 command. It seems to write the path twice, with the second time recoding the spaces in the filepath (as %20): C:\Users\Desktop\Images 1234\//users/Desktop/Images%201234   so the doc isn't written & therefore can't be opened- which makes sense.

Comment: Well, It works on my computer. Which version of R are you using? Also, do not use spaces or special characters in the filepath. Moreover, you can use different paths in the code. That might solve your problem. Also, I do not think the filepath C:\Users\Desktop\Images 1234\//users/Desktop/Images%201234 is a valide one. I think this might be the reason you have a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your continued assistance. Version 4.2.2. Spaces in the filepath are beyond my control (someone else's filing system).  I agree that the filepath isn't valid- that's not how it's written when I define it (path_Word<-"C:\users\Desktop\Images 1234.docx"). If I run the previous line (doc<-) & manually SaveAs from Word, it Saves to the correct place. But when I run the doc$SaveAs2(path_Word) line, NULL response, & if I manually try to SaveAs from Word, it tries to save it with the 2nd phrase of the filepath (C:\Users\Desktop\Images 1234\//users/Desktop/Images%201234)

Comment: Can you change the filepath to save the document? For example, can you do doc$SaveAs2(path_Word_Desktop) where path_Word_Desktop is a path to your desktop? Did you try this approach?

Comment: It does write the pdf to the Desktop- cool. There's still the same error message after the wordApp$$SaveAs But if I ignore it & carry on, it seems to function, but doesn't return any text after the strsplit command. [[1]] character(0). When I open the pdf, the image is rotated 180degrees. I don't know if it's just because it doesn't OCR anything- because all the text is upside down, or something else. Is there a way to dictate the orientation of the image when it's written to the docx (also 'upside down') so that I can see if that's the OCR problem?

Comment: I think you get the error because of the Bug. Which error are you getting?

Comment: <checkErrorInfo> -2147352567 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
Error: Exception occurred.

Comment: Are you using MacOS or Windows?

Comment: Windows 11, Thanks

Comment: What are the paths variable that you are using for the code? What values are you using for path_PDF, path_JPG and path_Word?

Comment: You asking this seems to have gotten me a step closer. Previously I had been using "C:/Users/gvash/desktop/tqyk2.jpg"; "C:/Users/gvash/desktop/PDF.pdf"; "C:/Users/gvash/desktop/DOC.docx". If I change the filenames to all being tqyk2, now I can see the desired text in the word document after doc$SaveAs2; but when I then try to $SaveAs, I still get the same error. Could it be because the file is open?

Comment: If you can see the text in the word document, you could simply extract the text from the Word document. That could be even simpler. You could skip the step of converting the Word document to PDF. Maybe something is missing on your computer that prevents the conversion from Word to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to extract the 5 digit number with the following code with tesseract :

```
library(tesseract)
library(magick)
path_PDF <- "D:\\stackoverflow_im.pdf"
path_PNG <- "D:\\stackoverflow_im.jpg"

pdf(path_PDF, height = 24, width = 12)
im <- image_read(path_PNG)
plot(im)
dev.off()

im <- image_read_pdf(path_PDF)
strsplit(ocr(im), "\n")

[1] "r oS ."                                                                                                                    
[2] "Sod La . - a x"                                                                                                            
[3] "ee A: ° : G"                                                                                                               
[4] "= “ng - . ie]"                                                                                                             
[5] "iad eee Oe : o"                                                                                                            
[6] ". APi ; ."                                                                                                                 
[7] "; fe ig Sa —— = = * = ="                                                                                                   
[8] "——— eee ."                                                                                                                 
[9] "ce A"                                                                                                                      
[10] "y - - ™ ~"                                                                                                                 
[11] ". ~~ . ae ee ee ‘\\"                                                                                                       
[12] "J ec, —— . ss in ——_—— ———— Y"                                                                                             
[13] "y 7 ———_* , : ia: OO"                                                                                                      
[14] ". y / , a Bian Kae Ri 2 : . . ~ :"                                                                                         
[15] "7 ee - . ce"                                                                                                               
[16] "’ _ ~ rf"                                                                                                                  
[17] "} = 72 : ; : a Te ns ——  aiaiaieae ee *s : t : eH"                                                                         
[18] "= nk BLES 2 1"                                                                                                             
[19] "= Bay/C] Block} 755 | *™ ay Mol ="                                                                                         
[20] ", | : 2752"                                                                                                                
[21] "| \\ —f nd e : >f RIFE \\"                                                                                                 
[22] "| = Block| Middle Dock RETRIEV"                                                                                            
[23] ". = 94/9022"                                                                                                               
[24] "i) im a. | Cl 2752| 2199€"                                                                                                 
[25] "ti | 21996 — ;"                                                                                                            
[26] ". VN ="                                                                                                                    
[27] "me = QQ"                                                                                                                   
[28] "—v = eetrieved ‘: 4"                                                                                                       
[29] "; a 5 BRetrievec CI 2752"
```

Comment: I'm making a few assumptions, but can't get this to work. I'm assuming you've saved the image as 'D:\\stackoverflow_im.jpg'; & you're creating a blank pdf 'D:\\stackoverflow_im.pdf'.
The dev.off() command gives me 'Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1(the null device)' so I've swapped in 'while (!is.null(dev.list())) dev.off()'
But when I run the 'im <- image_read_pdf(path_PDF)' command, I get 'PDF error: Invalid page count 0'

Comment: Hi, yes, I saved your image as 'D:\\stackoverflow_im.jpg'. I did not create a blank PDF. With the code, it transforms the image to a PDF document. Once the image is transformed into a PDF document, I apply the OCR on the PDF document and it is able to extract the number directly. I have used this technique in many projects at my job.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows but should be very similar for Linux/Mac

for deskew see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72701494/10802527

You can simply ask tesseract to output the results which you filter for numbers and then use the number for REN  now the issue is what to do if there is no number so you need to report that too

[image]

So we need to capture that output (I would usually be using a 2nd redirect to result.txt) and parse result again with the filename variable, however as your using "r", I will leave that secondary task to you.

```
tesseract.exe %filename.ext% temp -l eng --psm 11 & type temp.txt |findstr /R "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

Comment: I liked this answer, but am working on using the following to get it to run directly in R:
KJ <- tesseract(options = list(classify_use_pre_adapted_templates='-l',
                               tessedit_pageseg_mode='11', 
                               tessedit_create_txt='1')) THEN

text<-ocr(input,engine=KJ)